# Issues with global Mysqli Connection

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having an issue with the mysqli connection. I have three class files and a config file. The main class file is where I initialize the mysqli connection the other two class files extend the main class but the connection is not being inherited and I am getting an error when making a query.

config.php

```
<?php
include '-classes/Application.php';
include '-classes/class1.php';
include '-classes/class2.php';
define('DBHOST', '<HOST>');
define('DBUSER', '<USER>');
define('DBPASS', '<PASS>');
define('DBNAME', '<NAME>');
$app = new Application();
$c1 = new Class1();
$c2 = new Class2();
$c1->usernameExists('username');
```

Application.php

```
class Application {

    function __construct(){
        # Establish Connection to database
        $conn = mysqli_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DBNAME);
        # Check Database Connection
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {

            die("Failed to connect with MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error());
        } 
        else {
            $this->connect = $conn;
        }
    }
}
```

Class1 and Class2 .php

```
class Class1 extends Application{
    public function usernameExists($username) {
        $query = "SELECT `username` FROM `account` WHERE `username`='$username'";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connect, $query ) or die(mysqli_error($this->connect));
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) return true;
        return false;
}
```

Sometimes I will get this error:
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in class1.php on line #

and sometimes I will get no response at all...

Comment: Why should the connection be inherited? You have __three__ objects and each has it's own connection.

Comment: Are you sure it is connecting properly in your `if()`?

Comment: @u_mulder I have done this before. Only reason I'm making this is because it's no longer working for me and I don't understand why. Typically variables are passed down by the parent class. If they are set with a value they will be inherited.

Comment: You don't define `connect` outside of the __construct function, so the class doesn't know if it should be private, public, or protected.

Comment: @NathanRobb I'm pretty sure. Been doing this this way for a long time.

Comment: @aynber `public` by default.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thanks. I tend to just go ahead and define variables like that so my IDE doesn't complain. :-D

Comment: Properties can be inherited by child class. But objects of different classes don't know anything about ech other. So, once again, no connections are inherited. You have __three__ objects with __three__ different connections.

Comment: Using `die` isn't a good way of managing errors.  Using a constructor to do initialisation like this can be bad as there is no return value to check if it's worked or not.  Use prepared statements as they offer all sorts of benefits.

Comment: @NigelRen I'm using die for now for debugging purposes. I'll be adding exception handling later on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mantain the connection to be used on whole class, then, define first the variable.

```
class Application {
    [private | public] $connect;

    function __construct(){
        # Establish Connection to database
        $this->connect = mysqli_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DBNAME) or die("Failed to connect with MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error());
    }
}
```

Also, if you're using die to manage exceptions, you didn't need to reassign the variable to another one.

The variable $connect are defined as private if you only want to be accesed inside class, or public, if you want to can be used outside of them.

Comment: Define type of variable: private or public, as you need it.

Comment: Omg, whoever downvoted this, do you even know PHP? obviously he was just saying to choose between public or private. Wow.

Comment: I've forgot on first instance to specify type, but, yes, if you know any PHP, you know a variable inside on a class need a type.

Comment: The code was edited AFTER the downvote, previously it didn't have anything before the $connect.

Comment: So this did not really solve my problem... here is the thing... I am trying to limit the number of connections I am making. My server only allows 10 connections per user per hour. This is going to be a big application with a lot of class files. How can I do this connection thing globally without going over that limit?

Comment: and I am still getting a null in some queries in some classes even after doing the variable. Some classes work fine, then some classes produce this null error.

Comment: This code will only works with the class Application or a class who extends them. If you have a connection limit, you can create only one connection in whole code, for example, creating the variable $connect in the core and doing global $connect to them.